# kohana ORM factory does not show newly added column in database

Tags: kohana

I get this error,when i added a new column 'custom_url'.

I already had an instance of the ORM,when i fetch or try to save data for new column it gives me error saying that custom_url property does not exist.

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The custom_url property does not exist in the Model_Event class
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `PDO` driver? Because then you manually need to add all columns to the model's [`_table_columns`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#property%3a_table_columns).